# How to insert XML document to xml

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I have a XML document that I have to insert into data set..
Here's the part of the code:

```
 string XmlFilePath = "C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\Test_AGR_2.xml";
 XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 XmlDoc.Load(XmlFilePath);
```

So this XmlDoc I have to insert into a data-set but without any conversion to string  or what so ever!.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can load XML directly to DataTable with DataTable.ReadXml function, then add DataTable to your DataSet.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0z9zxd(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTable.ReadXml function, BUT, the xml schema must be coherent to the dataset class.
The xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<testDS>
  <testDT>
    <testCol>0</testCol>
  </testDT>
  <testDT>
    <testCol>1</testCol>
  </testDT>
  <testDT>
    <testCol>2</testCol>
  </testDT>
</testDS>
```

Instead you have to manually parse xml using XmlDocument and create the dataset with the data that you read.